# OpenLayers button triggered functions problems

Tags: javascript, function, button, openlayers

i´m adding some toggle_type buttons to an OpenLayers Panel to turn on/off a vector layer ( each button controls a vector layer visibility). The map has a selectFeature event listener too, which shows feature attributes in another div.

It works when coding for just a layer. But if I change my code to use arrays for adding several layers problems start.
I use an array (capasVectoriales) to store created vector layers from JSON files. Doing this, button triggered deactivate function starts to do strange things, not removing the layer and keeping the features "printed" on the map (not moving when you pan and zoom). 
 When i activate again the button the features act as expected.I can remove layer using map.removeLayer(map.layers[1]) from Firebug.
Here´s the code,

```
            function init() { .....

            capaRestauracion=capasVectoriales[0];

            var funcionActivarRestauracion= function() {
                map.addLayer(capaRestauracion);
                console.log('turn on' + capaRestauracion.name);
            };
            var funcionDesactivarRestauracion= function() {
                map.removeLayer(capaRestauracion);
                console.log('turno off ' + capaRestauracion.name);
            };

            // create type_toggle button
            var botonRestauracion = new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
                displayClass : 'boton' + capa,
                eventListeners : {
                    'activate' : funcionActivarRestauracion,
                    'deactivate' : funcionDesactivarRestauracion
                },
                title : 'Activar/Desactivar ' + capa,
                type : OpenLayers.Control.TYPE_TOGGLE
            });

            //create an external panel
            panelExterno = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel({
                div : document.getElementById("panel")
            });
            //add buttons to external panel

            panelExterno.addControls([botonRestauracion]);

            // add panel to map
            map.addControl(panelExterno);


            //activate button

            panelExterno.controls[0].activate();

            // create the select feature control
            var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(capasVectoriales, {
                hover : true,
                autoActivate : true
            });


            map.addControl(selector);
```

It seems there is a problem when i try to replace the "capaVectorial" variable with "capaVectorial[0]" array item, but don´t understand why.

Comment: The problem is the Control.SelectFeature expression. I have to add the selector for capasVectoriales[0] vector_layer object, not capasVectoriales array. I read somewhere that´s how you add a select features control to various vector layers. So, now muy question is: how to add a control selector feature to a various vector layers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the Control.SelectFeatures admits an array. I solved this with a layer.setVisibility, not adding and removing layers. Seems that when you add the selector, another layer is added to the map ("OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature_46_container"). If you remove any layer, you still see it, just like a fly on a TV: you can zoom and pan but removed layer features stay in same coordinates of the div. If you remove that SelectFeature_X_container, then button triggered functions work. I don´t understand why that container layer appears. Any idea?

Comment: Seem to have found OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.RootContainer!